# Using Playwright Is there a way to WaitForSelectorAsync inside of a specific frame?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, playwright

I wrote a couple of extension methods to simplify common test actions like this.

```
public static async Task WaitForElementToBeShown(this IPage page, string selector, int maxWaitInSeconds = 30, bool tolerateMultiples = true) {
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(selector, new PageWaitForSelectorOptions { State = WaitForSelectorState.Visible, Strict = !tolerateMultiples, Timeout = maxWaitInSeconds * 1000 });
        }
```

Unfortunately this times out if the element is in a frame.

Is there a way to wait for an element inside a specific frame?

Is there a way to wait for an element to be shown regardless of it's frame?

I know I could wrap the following in a loop and wait for it to be true but I was hoping that playwright had implemented something already.

```
await _page.FrameLocator("frame locator").Locator("some selector").IsVisibleAsync();
```

also I think this will throw an exception if the locator isn't unique. Is there a way to make this line tolerate multiples like the WaitForSelectorAsync method?